# Problem when maping array - React with Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following problem: I use a fatch API to get all the products I have registered in my database (mongodb), then I store the result in a slice called products-slice which has an array as its initial state empty. Until then everything is in order. As I need information the time the homepage is loaded, I use the useEffect hook to fetch the products I have registered. Then I pass this array as props to a component, and make a map. The problem is that when the component loads, the information is not local.

código do backend

```
module.exports.fetchProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await Product.find({});
    if (products) {
      res.json(products);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

productsActions.js

```
export const fetchProducts = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {

    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:xxxx/xxxxxx");
      const data = await response.json();
      let loadedProducts = [];
      for (const key in data) {
        loadedProducts.push({
          id: data[key]._id,
          productName: data[key].productName,
          price: data[key].price,
          imageUrl: data[key].imageUrl,
        });
      }
      dispatch(setProducts(loadedProducts));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

home.jsx

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

import {fetchProducts} from '../../store/actions/productsActions';
import Hero from "../hero/Hero";
import Footer from "../footer/Footer";
import DisplayProductsList from "../displayProduct/DisplayProductsList";

export default function Home() {
  const productsInfo = useSelector((state) => state.products.products);
  console.log(productsInfo);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Hero />
      <DisplayProductsList products={productsInfo} />
      <Container fluid>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

product-slice.js

```
const initialState = {
  products: [],
};

const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "product",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setProducts(state, action) {
      state.products.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
});

export const { setProducts } = productSlice.actions;
export default productSlice.reducer;
```

component where I'm mapping

```
export default function DisplayProductsList(props) {
 console.log(props);
  return (
      props.products.map((product) => (
        <DisplayProducts
        key={product.id}
        imageUrl={product.imageUrl}
        name={product.productName}
        price={product.price}
        />
      ))
  );
}
```

console.log output in the above component
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DwBW.png)

Comment: the screenshot you have provided shows the data as a 2d array. you should look at how `setProducts` works.. instead of pushing an array of items onto the existing array (`state.products.push`), you want to concatenate the arrays together (`state.products.concat(action.payload)`).